# Ascii to Hex conversion error

Tags: java, hex, ascii, type-conversion

I have a problem, when I try to convert `'é'` to Hex, it gives me the error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte"`
The code is below:

```
public  byte[] convertUnicode(String msg){
      byte[] data = new byte[msg.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
      switch (msg.charAt(i)) {
        case 'E':  data[i] = 0x45; break;
        case 'è':  data[i] = 0xE9; break;
        default:   data[i] = 0x3F; break; // '?'
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to cast to (byte) for values over 0x7F (127, the maximum value for Java's signed byte), otherwise the literal is treated as an int.

`data[i] = (byte)0xE9;`

However it looks like you're trying to get String's bytes in a particular encoding, which is a lot easier to do with

```
byte[] bytes = msg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");  // Or any other encoding of your choice
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print the value of '0xE9' its 233 which exceeds the value of byte which is -127 to +127. Therefore you will need to typecast it to byte.